# Function FindControl is not working

Tags: html, asp.net, vb.net, findcontrol

I'm trying to get the value of dynamically created textbox.

```
Dim idReponse As String
idReponse = GlobalVariableAddOneWeight.ArrayReponseId(i)

Dim textboxId As String
textboxId = "txtWeight" + idReponse

Dim tb As New TextBox()
tb = Me.Div2.FindControl(textboxId)

Dim Poids As Integer = CInt(tb.Text)
```

I already tried the same code in another page and its working but in this one i'm having this error:

> object reference not set to an instance of an object

Comment: Where is this code within your chain of events? Page_Load? Some databound event?

Comment: It would be helpful to know exactly what line is erroring and what object is not being set.

Comment: it is erroring on the last line "Dim Poids As Integer = CInt(tb.Text)"

Comment: this code is in save button click event

Comment: If it is in the button click event, then I suspect that you are not dynamically creating the control when the page is post back. This means that the control doesn't actually exist. Try making sure that you have added it before finding it.

Comment: Im sure that the controls (textbox) are correctly added, since i can see them when when i load the page!

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that `tb` isn't actually getting set to anything.

Ensure that `Div2` is actually the current naming container for the element with an id of `textboxId`.

Additionally, you will need to cast `tb` to a `TextBox` in order to call its `Text` property.  I would break it down like this to try to narrow down the problem:

```
Dim obj as Object = Me.Div2.FindControl(textboxId)
Dim tb as TextBox = CType(obj, TextBox)
Dim Poids As Integer = CInt(tb.Text)
```

This way you can see if the problem is with getting the object itself with `FindControl` or with casting the object to a `TextBox`.

Comment: 'Div2' is the container for the element with an id of textboxId